# Recovering Cassandra Data From Files

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, disaster-recovery

I have a development machine that had a single-node Cassandra 2.1.2 setup. The main drive failed, but the secondary drive, mounted at /var, is good. I was able to connect this drive to another system with a working OS and Cassandra install and mount it.

I can see the files for my database under /var/cassandra/data// and would like to recover that data. Nothing outside of /var survived -- no configs or binaries.

Is it as simple as copying that directory to the /var/cassandra/data/ directory on the good system, or is there some other more detailed procedure for recovering/importing that data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to remember from your config files - is what was the partitioner. Now you should save your data files somewhere safe, create another single-node cluster, then follow the procedure described [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_snapshot_restore_new_cluster.html).

The files in your saved data folder is what in these manuals is referred to as snapshot.